# MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature won't refresh

Tags: powershell, wmi, temperature

I want to read temperature sensors from my motherboard in PowerShell 5.1. Unfortunately the corresponding WMI-object won't fetch new values if I call it more than once. Even restarting PowerShell won't help. The only way to get new data is to reboot my PC and run the code again...

My code:

```
Write-Host "Temperatures:"
Write-Host "-------------"
$ThermalZones = Get-WmiObject -Class MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi"
$ThermalZones = $ThermalZones | Where -Property CurrentTemperature -gt 0
$ThermalZones | ForEach {"$($_.InstanceName.Replace('ACPI\ThermalZone\', '')): $($_.CurrentTemperature / 10 - 273) [°C]"}
```

I noticed there is a "SamplingPeriod" property for each zone which is 0 by default every time I re-run the code but changing it seems to have no effect... Can I somehow force a refresh?

Comment: There's another script [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/TemperatureUtils/1.0.1/Content/TemperatureUtils.psm1), but as have been mentioned, this is probably not the core temp of the CPU, as the WMI object depends on accessibility in the BIOS and some other magic.

Answer (score 0):

The temperature is updated, if Speedfan is started.
This is one way to force the refresh.
Or log off an log on again.

Unfortunately the parameter SamplingPeriod can not be set but only requested.